# How do I draw a cylinder in OpenTK(.Glu.Cylinder)?

Tags: opengl, opengl-3, opentk

How do I draw a cylinder with OpenGL in OpenTK?

Comment: or any OpenTK.Glu.Cylinder example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample code from an older project of mine. This creates an "uncapped" cylinder (top and bottom are empty).

```
int segments = 10; // Higher numbers improve quality 
int radius = 3;    // The radius (width) of the cylinder
int height = 10;   // The height of the cylinder

var vertices = new List<Vector3>();
for (double y = 0; y < 2; y++)
{
    for (double x = 0; x < segments; x++)  
    {
        double theta = (x / (segments - 1)) * 2 * Math.PI;

        vertices.Add(new Vector3()
        {
            X = (float)(radius * Math.Cos(theta)),
            Y = (float)(height * y),
            Z = (float)(radius * Math.Sin(theta)),
        });
    }
}

var indices = new List<int>();
for (int x = 0; x < segments - 1; x++)
{
    indices.Add(x);
    indices.Add(x + segments);
    indices.Add(X + segments + 1);

    indices.Add(x + segments + 1);
    indices.Add(x + 1);
    indices.Add(x);
}
```

You can now render the cylinder like this:

```
GL.Begin(BeginMode.Triangles);
foreach (int index in indices)
    GL.Vertex3(vertices[index]);
GL.End();
```

You can also upload vertices and indices into a vertex buffer object to improve performance.

Comment: Fiddler, your code works well. Can you please explain indices mapping with vertices? Initially you are calculating vertices for bottom and top circle of cylinder then you are mapping these vertices to indices. The sequence is not clear to me. Can you mark these segment in a sample image?

Comment: Vertices are points in 3d space. Indices describe how to connect these points into triangles (three vertices per triangle). See here for more details: http://www.opentk.com/doc/chapter/2/opengl/geometry/primitives

Answer (score 1):

Generating the geometry for a cylinder is quite simple (let's consider a Z-aligned cylinder). Let me use pseudocode:

```
points = list of (x,y,z)
    where x = sin(a)*RADIUS, y = cos(a)*RADIUS, z = b,
    for each a in [0..2*PI) with step StepA,
    for each b in [0..HEIGHT] with step StepB
```

About the indices: Let us assume `N` equal to the number of "levels" or "slices" of the cylinder (which depends on HEIGHT and StepB) and `M` equal to the number of points on every "slice" (which depends on StepA).

The cylinder contains some quads, each spanning 2 neighbouring slices, so the indices would look like:

```
indices = list of (a,b,c,d)
    where a = M * slice + point,
          b = M * slice + (point+1) % M,
          c = (M+1) * slice + (point+1) % M,
          d = (M+1) * slice + point
    for each slice in [0..N-2]
    for each point in [0..M-1]
```

If you need normals for the cylinder, they are simple to generate:

```
normals = (x/RADIUS,y/RADIUS,0)
    for each (x,y,z) in points
```

That's it for the round part of the cylinder, you might also want the "caps" but I believe they are easy to do.

I'll leave the fun part of translating my pseudocode into your language of choice for you. :)

The rest is to create/bind the VBO, load up the geometry, set pointers, use your shader of choice and call glDrawArrays(...) - any OpenGL 3 tutorial should cover this; are you familiar with that part?

Comment: Sorry I dont understand your pseudocode. I have located OpenTK.Glu.Cylinder but am having problems getting it to work, maybe you are able to help me with that if you use OpenTK? ty

Comment: Your question originally mentioned OpenGL 3 and VBO which suggested to me that you'd like to generate the geometry by yourself. Can you describe your problems with Glu.Cylinder?

Comment: Please do not use Glu.Cylinder. Glu was deprecated in OpenGL 3.0 and is no longer supported.